# How does Gradle/Android Studio create the ash folder for each dependency during build?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, hash, android-gradle-plugin

**How does Gradle/Android Studio create the ash folder for each dependency  during build?**

I am trying to build code that will look at the dependencies in my application to put together some graphs (not important for my question). I noticed that the dependencies for my application are in a hash. How is this hash being generated? I would like to know the mechanics behind it.

---

I tried the gradle documentation but could not find the answer.

I am using:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
```

Every time I rebuild a new folder with a new hash for each of the libs gets created. So I am wondering how is that hash calculated.